# Is there a difference between these two notations, $f(x)$ and $f((x))$?

Tags: functions, notation

I'm curious, are these two notations same or different? If they are different, can anybody point out difference?

That is, is $f(x)$ and $f((x))$ the same thing? Similarly, what about $f(x,y)$ and $f((x,y))$?

Comment: Where have you encountered this notation?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace "I'm curious"... Idk if this is even a thing. But it wouldn't hurt to confirm it

Answer (score 3):

In some cases parentheses alone are notation for a nontrivial operation.

For example, in ring theory $(x)$ can mean the ideal generated by $x$, which is different from $x$ itself. So if a function takes subsets of the ring as arguments, applying it to a principal ideal would be written $f((x))$.

For another example, $(x,y)$ may -- other than an ordered pair -- be the notation for an *open interval* of the real line. If $f$ is a function that takes values that are subsets of $\mathbb R$, the right way to apply it to the open unit interval would be $f((0,1))$.

In other cases it might simply be a typo.

Note that even though programming languages generally allow you to write as many redundant parentheses as you want, this is avoided in mathematics. Parentheses that serve a reasonable purpose of disambiguating expressions are fair game, but an *additional* set of parentheses just for the heck of it will leave the reader confused whether something like the above examples is in place.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen that notation and it seems it could be more interpretable in the world of programming.

Then, they are not the same. $f(x,y)$ is a function of $2$ variables and $f((x,y))$ is a function of $1$ variable that is a $2$-dimensional vector.
I suppose the same holds for the first example, so that $(x)$ is some kind of a natotion for $1$-dimensional vector.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ usually refers to a function of one single variable. For example $$f(x)=x^2$$ while in some scenarios $f((x))$ refers to a function of a vector or any other multi-dimension variable. In that case we have $(x)=(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n)$ where $x_i$s are all single variables. For example $$f((x))=x_1^2+\cdots +x_n^2$$ generally such a notation relies on the question clarification since there are various cases to distinguish these notations.